# Style file inclusion

Tags: css, wp-register-style

I am trying to include a `flexslider.css` file with this code:

```
wp_register_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css' );
if( is_page( 'home' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider' );
}
```

but it is not working this way, any idea why? trying to solve this one for a whole day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook it to an action.

Add the below code to the theme's **functions.php** file. It should work.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_flexslider_css' );
function theme_flexslider_css() {
    wp_register_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css' ); 
    if( is_page( 'home' ) ) { 
        wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider' ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `function theme_styles() {    wp_register_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css' );
 if( is_page( 'home' ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider' );
 }    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles', );`    still did not work